# Lua: give custom userdata a tostring method

Tags: c++, lua, tostring

I have a custom userdata in lua.  When I execute `tostring` on an instance of the userdata (inside Lua), it always returns a string like `"userdata: 0xaddress"`.  I would like it to return the name of the userdata (`"Point: 0xaddress"`), meaning that I want to override the `tostring` to include a case for my userdata.  Does anyone know if this can be done?

```
#define check_point(L) \
    (Point**)luaL_checkudata(L,1,"Point")

static int 
luaw_point_getx(lua_State* L)
{
    Point** point_ud = check_point(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, (*point_ud)->x);
    return 1;
}

static int 
luaw_point_gety(lua_State* L)
{
    Point** point_ud = check_point(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, (*point_ud)->y);
    return 1;
}

void 
luaw_point_push(lua_State* L, Point* point)
{
    Point** point_ud = (Point**)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(Point*));
    *point_ud = point;
    luaL_getmetatable(L, "Point");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
}

static const struct luaL_Reg luaw_point_m [] = {
    {"x", luaw_point_getx},
    {"y", luaw_point_gety},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int 
luaopen_wpoint(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "WEAVE.Point");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    luaL_register(L, NULL, luaw_point_m);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide a `__tostring` metamethod, in the similar way you wrote the `__index`.

```
// [...]
int luaw_point_index(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_pushfstring(L, "Point: %p", lua_topointer(L, 1));
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_wpoint(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "WEAVE.Point");
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, luaw_point_index);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__tostring");
    luaL_register(L, NULL, luaw_point_m);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @NicolBolas why only in Lua 5.2? It should work in Lua 5.1, AFAIK

Comment: Because that's how 5.1 works. Only Lua's `tostring` method will call the `__tostring` "metamethod". Just search [the docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html); the only mention of it is made in relation to Lua's `tostring` method. Whereas [5.2's docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html) mentions it in *any* string conversion routine, even `luaL_tolstring` and `lua_tostring` which is defined in terms of `luaL_tolstring`.

Comment: Only with 5.2? I thought that luaL_register was deprecated in Lua 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override `tostring` so that it checks to see if the value is one of its custom types. If it is, then use your own function to get the name. If not, pass it to the overridden `tostring`. This is generally done by putting the original `tostring` in an upvalue and then replacing the global `tostring` with that.